# "java" succeeds," java emmarun" fails

Tags: java, emma

Disclaimer: I am new to java and emma.  Details:

- I installed emma, and have worked through some of the examples.  No problems.
- I have a java project with a number of files that I wish to get a coverage report.
- I type "javac -d out *.java".  No errors.
- I type "java -cp out Main".  The program runs fine and I get the expected output.
- I type "java emmarun -cp out Main".  I get the following:

  emmarun: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [Main] does not have a runnable public main() method
  Exception in thread "main" com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [Main] does
  not have a runnable public main() method
          at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner._run(AppRunner.java:546)
          at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner.run(AppRunner.java:97)
          at com.vladium.emma.runCommand.run(runCommand.java:247)
          at emmarun.main(emmarun.java:27)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner$Invoker can not access a member of clas
  s Main with modifiers "public static"
          at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner$Invoker.run(AppRunner.java:655)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

My "Main.java" file looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        NetworkSimplexTest nst = new NetworkSimplexTest();
        nst.test();
    }
}
```

I would post all the code, but it is rather lengthy.  The simpler examples I tried work fine - emma automatically instruments and creates a coverage report, just like in the examples.

It appears that Emma cannot find my "Main", but regular java can.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is it a typo that the above doesn't have a `public` modifier?

Comment: I see a public in "public static void main( String() args )", or is "public" required somewhere else?

Comment: The class? I don't know if that will solve your problem, but I'd sure start with it, because it's easy.

Comment: OK - my java ignorance is definitely showing.  Adding the "public" to the "class" definition worked fine.  Thanks.

Comment: Awesome :) I'll convert the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Emma will expect the class to be defined as `public`, which was missing in your original code.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, what with it being right and all.