# Can't run EMMA code coverage

Tags: java, code-coverage, emma

I have Java SE Development Kit 7u3 installed

I've been through some of the topics similar to this (e.x. ["java" succeeds," java emmarun" fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549362/java-succeeds-java-emmarun-fails)) but my problem is that EMMA doesn't work for me at all. After I run:

```
java -cp emma.jar emmarun -cp . Main
```

it always says:

```
[EMMA v2.0, build 5312]
emmarun: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [Main] does not have a runnable public main() method
Exception in thread "main" com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [Main] does not have a runnable public main() method
        at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner._run(AppRunner.java:497)
        at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner.run(AppRunner.java:97)
        at com.vladium.emma.runCommand.run(runCommand.java:247)
        at emmarun.main(emmarun.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11 in method Main.<init>()V at offset 4
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner._run(AppRunner.java:493)
```

Compilation runs well ("javac Main.java") and application is working (I get the expected output from "java Main"). The code of Main.java is simple HelloWorld application.

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
```

I just wanted to run emmarun on any example code to see if it's working. Well, it is not. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://emma.sourceforge.net/intro.html your statement to run emma doesn't look right.

Comment: yes, I tried that too for a .jar file, with the same effect

Comment: Have you tried making your java filename match the classname? (both HelloWorld, or both Main)

Comment: Yes, I have. Didn't help unluckily.

Comment: All the docs show `...emma.jar emmarun ...`, why are you not using `emmarun`?

Comment: sorry, that's a mistake in my first post. I'll edit it to show the exact command I was using.

Comment: java -cp emma.jar emmarun -cp . HelloWorld ?

Comment: That is right. I changed it in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be popping up in a few places. The solutions I have discovered so far are these:

- Since you are using Java 7, it might be an issue with your emma plugin (if using eclipse). Apparently installing the beta for this plugin allows use of Java 7: Link: [Testng, Emma, Cobertura, coverage and JDK 7 result in ClassFormatError and VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010665/testng-emma-cobertura-coverage-and-jdk-7-result-in-classformaterror-and-verif)
- Comments from the same link talk about using the Java JVM option '-X:+UseSplitVerifier' to solve it too.